# How can i read data effectively from cloud store?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                    horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text(
                        'Enter user name to search',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          //Do something with the user input.
                        },
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter your password.',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                          stream: _usersStream,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return const Text('Something went wrong');
                            }
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const Text("Loading");
                            }
                            return ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              children: snapshot.data!.docs
                                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(data['username']),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            );
                          })
                    ]))));
  }
}
```

Hello am new to flutter and currently working on a chat app. am having challenge loading all registered users. above is my code and i read the documentary on firebase cloud store site but its not working. Please I need and help on geting all registered users from the collection

I use the code for streambuilder from the cloud store official documentary but it didn't work for me

Comment: what error does it show to you

Comment: Checkout firebase security rules